# Some errors php

Tags: parsing, syntax

I need some help to solved this error;

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE
```

The Line is:

```
list( $fname, $size ) = fname                    $fname = trim( $fname );}"
```

Begin of the code:

```
include( "{$include_path}/app/ftp.php" );
        $ftp_object = new FTP( "" );
        $ftp_object->login( $remote_store_array, $remote_store_array['user_login'], $decoded_temp_passwd );
        unset( $decoded_temp_passwd );
        $singlerow_archive = query_singlerow( $table = "store_files", "`id` = '{$singlerow_install['file_id']}'" );
        $ftp_object->file_size( $singlerow_archive['file'] );
        $zip_array = $ftp_object->listzips( );
        $ftp_object->logout( );
        $percent_uploaded = "";
        $archive_mb_size = sprintf( "%.1f", $singlerow_archive['size'] / 1024 / 1024 );
        if ( !empty( $zip_array ) )
        {
            foreach ( $zip_array as $fileinfo )
            {
                list( $fname, $size ) = fname                    $fname = trim( $fname );
                $size = trim( $size );
                }
                if ( !( $singlerow_archive['file'] == $fname ) && empty( $size ) )
                {
                    $percent_uploaded = sprintf( "%.1f", $size / $singlerow_archive['size'] * 100 );
                }
            }
        }
        if ( empty( $percent_uploaded ) )
        {
            $percent_uploaded = "0";
        }
        array_push( $admin_diag_msg, translate_text( "tpl_store_archive_upload_triggered", "upper" )." [ <span style=\"background-color : #ffffcc; padding : 5px;\">{$percent_uploaded} %</span> {$archive_mb_size} ".translate_text( "tpl_MB" )." ]" );
```

Comment: What is `fname` here (without a $)?

Comment: Hi,i gonna post more content and maybe we can solve this:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try : `list( $fname, $size ) = $fname;`

Comment: this problem it's solved thanks beautifulday,but know i have anoter error in the same file "unexpected T_CASE"